# awk print from mysql dump file

Tags: bash, scripting, sed, awk

I'm trying to extract data from mysqldump file, its a very big file, restoring it to database will take days, I'm trying to use sed or awk to extract data as the following

```
INSERT INTO `CallDetailRecord` VALUES (1706,1340684374803,1340684375823,1340684383013,'2253040012','2253040012','2253040012','4016487697',0,'225304001200','T',1,'','',0,7,1707,'LineTester','1101','57.6.app_linetester.1102@10.40.10.170','',5060,'10.40.10.45',5060,'1000003415761102_app_linetester@10.40.10.170','<sip:12253040012@10.40.10.45:5060>;tag=sansay420992041rdb3914','<sip:14016487697@10.40.10.170>;tag=100000342','200',0,'',0,NULL,'','^A',0,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO `CallDetailRecord` VALUES (1707,1340684381526,1340684381526,1340684388725,'3109757108','3109757108','','4016487697',0,'','P',0,'','',0,7,1708,'LineTest','1101','2.20.app_linetest.1103@10.40.10.170','10.40.10.40',5060,'',5060,'212122542-0-2277160422@74.112.124.121','<sip:3109757108@10.40.10.170>;tag=100000667','\"4016487697\" <sip:4016487697@10.40.10.40>;tag=sansay420992112rdb2348','200',0,'',0,NULL,'','^A',0,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO `CallDetailRecord` VALUES (1708,1340684380791,1340684381384,1340684389761,'3172850012','3172850012','3172850012','4016487697',0,'317285001200','T',1,'','',0,8,1709,'LineTester','1101','57.13.app_linetester.1102@10.40.10.170','',5060,'10.40.10.45',5060,'10000034357131102_app_linetester@10.40.10.170','<sip:13172850012@10.40.10.45:5060>;tag=sansay420992099rdb5677','<sip:14016487697@10.40.10.170>;tag=100000344','200',0,'',0,NULL,'','^A',0,NULL,NULL);
```

I would like the output to be

```
1706,1340684374803,1340684375823,1340684383013,'2253040012','2253040012','2253040012','4016487697',0,'225304001200','T',1,'','',0,7,1707,'LineTester','1101','57.6.app_linetester.1102@10.40.10.170','',5060,'10.40.10.45',5060,'1000003415761102_app_linetester@10.40.10.170','<sip:12253040012@10.40.10.45:5060>;tag=sansay420992041rdb3914','<sip:14016487697@10.40.10.170>;tag=100000342','200',0,'',0,NULL,'','^A',0,NULL,NULL
1707,1340684381526,1340684381526,1340684388725,'3109757108','3109757108','','4016487697',0,'','P',0,'','',0,7,1708,'LineTest','1101','2.20.app_linetest.1103@10.40.10.170','10.40.10.40',5060,'',5060,'212122542-0-2277160422@74.112.124.121','<sip:3109757108@10.40.10.170>;tag=100000667','\"4016487697\" <sip:4016487697@10.40.10.40>;tag=sansay420992112rdb2348','200',0,'',0,NULL,'','^A',0,NULL,NULL
1708,1340684380791,1340684381384,1340684389761,'3172850012','3172850012','3172850012','4016487697',0,'317285001200','T',1,'','',0,8,1709,'LineTester','1101','57.13.app_linetester.1102@10.40.10.170','',5060,'10.40.10.45',5060,'10000034357131102_app_linetester@10.40.10.170','<sip:13172850012@10.40.10.45:5060>;tag=sansay420992099rdb5677','<sip:14016487697@10.40.10.170>;tag=100000344','200',0,'',0,NULL,'','^A',0,NULL,NULL
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If a DB restore takes days, regardless of the size, you're doing something wrong. How big is the file? Does the dump contain something like ``ALTER TABLE `CallDetailRecord` DISABLE KEYS``?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

file a.awk:

```
BEGIN { FS = "VALUES \\(" }; 
"INSERT INTO \`CallDetailRecord\` VALUES" { sub( ");$", "", $2 ); print $2 };
```

run:

`cat mysqldump_file | awk -f a.awk`

Comment: This won't work if there are any of those `FS` characters in the database fields.

Comment: looks like its working, do you know how can I run it on a single line?

Comment: `cat mysqldump_file | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "VALUES \\(" }; "INSERT INTO` `\`CallDetailRecord\` VALUES" { sub( ");$", "", $2 ); print $2 };'`

Comment: thank you, I really appreciate your help! I have been an administration for few yesrs, yet, my awk skills needs lots of improvements.

Answer (score 2):

Using sed:

```
sed -e 's/^INSERT INTO `CallDetailRecord` VALUES (//' -e 's/);$//' mysqldump_file
```